# Sockets and ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets

I want to write a program that should allow clients to connect to each other, and possibly (if it's not too hard) share information/files. I want to keep the concept a bit like Bit torrent, where there is no server involved. There are only clients (who will also act as a server).

If I wanted to use a server, it would be easy to get started, since the server would be listening for incomming clients using the ServerSocket.

My question is... Do I still need to have a ServerSocket object in my client/Peer class? If not, how else would each client/peer connect to each other? The Socket doesn't seem to be enough here.

Should one have some examples on this, it would be paradise. Else an answer is also very fine

Answer (score 0):

If they connect to each other, both ways, then both need a server (ServerSocket) to accept incoming connections. When the server is listening to incoming connections and a client connects it creates a Socket that you could use to talk back but if there is no connection yet you still need a server on the other side and a client-socket (Socket) to connect to it. I'm talking about TCP connections. In the case that you use UDP you could broadcast and let multiple clients connect to it, still that is a server. 
So i think that if you configure your server and client-socket (Socket) on each peer to communicate with each other and follow a certain protocol, then you will achieve what you want.

Comment: I fixed your answer for you. Now it's wrong again. You have `Socket` and `ServerSocket` completely confused, and there is no such thing as a `Server` or a `ClientSocket.` -1

Comment: So when you say 'Server' and 'ClientSocket' what exactly do you mean? There are no classes by these names in the JDK. And if you don't mean classes, what do you mean? and why the capitalization? And a `ServerSocket` isn't created 'when a client connects'. I suggest you re-read what you have written. It doesn't make sense. You should revert to my edit, which *was* correct. [NB I've been an 'ICT engineer' myself for a while too, you won't get far with that line of defence. Don't bother suggesting that my knowledge is deficient, either. I've written books about this stuff.]

Comment: Server to not confuse the socket that is made when a ServerSocket accepts an incoming client connection. To make a distinction between the instance that is listening and the instance that is used to create the actual connection. The name of the class is not really relevant i think, it's the concepts which is important. http://examples.oreilly.com/jenut/Server.java

Comment: All that is already accomplished precisely and unambiguously by the class names `ServerSocket` and `Socket` which you *were* using, but you then mysteriously edited *out* of your answer, and it is *not* accomplished by your use of other terms whose meaning is known only to you, and which you spelt using conventions that apply to class names even though you apparently didn't intend them as class names. You're just causing confusion. I suggest you revert to my edit. If the citation you now provide is essential to understand your answer it should be cited in your answer.

Comment: Did you check the link and read the name or did you only read your books and ignore everything since? I didnt write that, it's an example from a 'real' book (which is not about punched cards like they used back in the days). CHECK AGAIN and please dont lecture me about naming conventions. examples.oreilly.com/jenut/Server.java

Comment: I'm trying to help you improve your answer. I've done so. You have now adopted all my suggestions. All this rudeness and irrelevance doesn't impress anybody.

Comment: Being rude is telling somebody that he doesnt understand something and saying that you know it better. Being polite would have been to ask what i mean like: What do you mean with Server and ServerSocket? The way i explained it was to make somebody, that doesnt have the right knowledge, to understand that there is a fundamental difference between a ServerSocket that listens and a ServerSocket that is connected to a client and communicating, even if those classnames dont exist in the Java API, it's common practice to use those names and the point was clear.

Comment: So im sorry if i was rude.

Answer (score -1):

> Do I still need to have a `ServerSocket` object in my client/Peer class?

Yes you do.